# How can I through an editable textview populate a custom todo list using a custom adaptor?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want a user to input data through an editable text and I want to receive that data through a custom made listview for that I am trying to use a custom adapter to add a textfield into my listview, through the `tostring()` method I have converted the data from the editable textview to a string and I am adding that string to the custom adaptor but I am having a type mismatch error, before this I added the string to a basic adapter and the listview was populating normally, what am I doing wrong?

User.java

```
public class User {

public String itemView;

public User(String itemView) {
    this.itemView = itemView;
}
```

todoFragment.java

```
public class todoFragment extends ListFragment {

private CheckBox mCheckBox;
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mToDoField;
private Button mAdd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.todo_title);
}

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        User user = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);
        }
        TextView todoTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_TextView);

        todoTextView.setText(user.itemView);
        return convertView;
    }
}

@TargetApi(9) // remember this for isEmpty()
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);

    ArrayList<User> todoList = new ArrayList<User>();
    final UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), todoList);
    ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) v.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
    listViewToDo.setAdapter(adapter);


    mAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String toDo = mToDoField.getText().toString().trim();

            if (toDo.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }

            adapter.add(toDo); // type mismatch error here
            mToDoField.setText("");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `toDo` is a String, and your ArrayAdapter `adapter` is of type `User`. So, when you try to call `adapter.add()`, the adapter is expecting a `User` object but you are passing it a string.

It appears to me that you don't really know what exactly you are doing. As of right now, the structure of your code implies that each item in your ArrayAdapter is its own user, with their own item. What you should be doing is creating a `User` object with an `ArrayList<String>` to hold all their to-do's. Your ArrayAdapter should extend `ArrayAdapter<String>` and you pass the to-do list to the Adapter, instead of a list of Users.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding A string Type to the `adapter` object, which extends `ArrayAdapter` of Type `User`, thats why you are getting type mismatch error, just set the value `todo` to your `User` Objet and then add object to `adapter`. hope this help you.